# Windows 10 Action Center Brightness Button not working

Tags: windows-10, brightness, action-center

I'm not sure if this is the right community to ask about this, so if there's somewhere else I should be, let me know please.

Until today, my brightness could be toggled using the action center (the 0%, 25%, 50%, etc.) However, today when I press the button, no action is conducted. I can change the brightness via other methods, but not through the action center. I tried restarting explorer, but it didn't work. Is there a fix?

[image: Here's a picture]

Comment: So what software or configuration changes did you make today?

Comment: Literally nothing. I have no idea why it changed all of a sudden.

Comment: I believe this week was patch Tuesday, so check, and see if any updates were installed

Comment: My last update was May 9th; My laptop is also up-to-date.

Comment: I think someone upvoted this, so I'll add that this problem went away after a restart. Every now and then, if it reappears, restarting helps :)

Comment: Is there any workaround except for restarting? I'm seeing this on a Dell-AW 13 r3.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have zero clue about all these advanced fixes. My go-to is turning my laptop on and off again ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯